# Django:How can I ensure that a view can only be directed from another view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have two views

```
def view1(request):
    do something
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(view2), args1)
```

Now  I need view2 to only work if it's referred by view1. How do I do that? I did read it somewhere, not able to recollect

```
@somefilter
def view2(request):
    do something
    #view2 will only be referred from view1, else Http404
```

Comment: As this is your 16th question on StackOverflow, surely by now you've noticed that every one has been edited by someone after you've asked it in order to correct the formatting of the code. There's a large orange question mark on the textbox where questions and answers are posted. This question mark links to a page that explains how to format your questions so that they are readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check for the `HTTP_REFERER` HTTP header. See the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META). Here is a [Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/179/) that gives you a decorator to check for referrers.

Comment: I would rather return the second view from the first one and not do redirect, then check for HTTP_REFERER since it's not very reliable value specially if you want security implemented this way.

Comment: @rebus: you are right. What you suggested would be a better approach.